# Echarts 5 line graph click to change colour not working

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I'm trying to make a line graph change color on mouse click by using the `select.lineStyle.color` attribute.
I'm able to trigger a colour change for the points upon mouse click using `select.itemStyle.color` and I'm expecting the `select.lineStyle.color` attribute to change the color of the graph but , it doesn't seem to work despite the documentation saying that `select` should work for all series.

I even programmatically fired the "select" event (not in the sandbox) but no changes were observed in my line graph.

[My code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apache-echarts-5-3-ssr-demo-forked-fvl7vl?file=/src/index.js)

---

Extract from the [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/release-note/v5-feature)

> In addition, we've added click to select to all series, an interaction that was previously only available in a few series such as pie charts and maps, allowing developers to set it to single or multiple selection mode, and to listen to the selectchanged event to get all the selected shapes for further processing. As with emphasis and blur, the selection style can also be configured in select.

Please help me. I've been working on this for a week and found no solutions here. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my answer directly via posting an [issue](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16545) on their Github page.

Apparently, `select` is only applicable for data object, not series objects(or whatever you call it). So this feature is not available.

What I did, like most people, is to listen to the `mouseclick` event and update the `series-line.lineStyle.opacity` property in `options` directly to blur out other lines. Set `triggerLineEvent:true` so that clicking any part of the line will fire the `mouseclick` event, instead of just the data points.